# Is it clear and natural to use "has to do with" to mean "related"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm aware of the meaning of "[be/have something to do with sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-have-something-to-do-with-sth)", which is

> to be related to something or a cause of something but not in a way that you know about or understand exactly

[A tutorial](https://youtu.be/T-HGdc8L-7w?t=597) uses a similar phrase

> this is all the data
> that **has to do with** this particular bubble.

I understand it means

> this is all the data
> that is related to this particular bubble.

The question is whether it's clear and natural to say "has to do with" in this context?

Comment: I think it is contextually correct to use "has to do with" in the above mentioned sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

It would (in my opinion) be more natural to say **has to do with** rather than **related to**.
Having said that both are correct but **related to** is a slightly more formal way of saying it.